# Diverging sequence $s_n$ so that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n−s_{n+1} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anybody find a diverging sequence $s_n$ so that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n−s_{n+1} = 0$$

Comment: $s_n=\log(n)$..

Answer (score 2):

The partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$ fits the bill.

In particular, $s_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ and $s_N - s_{N+1} = -\frac{1}{N+1}$. Moreover, the series itself diverges, which means $s_N \to \infty$.